# How can i stop my square from moving in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using python to create a snake game , as for now im trying to create a square that moves in a direction set by pressing an ARROW KEY, as example: 
if Right Arrow as been pressed, the square suppose to move in that direction until some other Arrow Key is pressed, i tried many diffrent things but nothing has worked for me so far. it actually moves where i want in the speed i want, but i cant change its direction
help will be apriciated. 
my code:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and add the code as text. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your approach to solving this problem, but I feel that there is a better way. You can set a variable equal to the direction the snake is moving, like `direction = "right"`. Then, every frame, you can move the current set direction and check for new user input, like this:

```
# Move your snake - You know how to do this, right?
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        direction = "right"
    # Continue for all four directions
```

Hope this helps!